# How to get email to show in color when typed in text?

Tags: hyperref, color

In LaTeX's `article` documentclass, how do I (using `hyperref`, if I understood right) get email links to show in color (say, red) when I type them in the middle of a paragraph?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on your preference, you could do any one of the following:

1. If you just want to typeset it in colour, without any linking capabilities, you could use

   ```
   \usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
   ...
   My email address is {\color{red} who@cares.com}.
   ```

   [image: Regular email in red]

   Note the scoping of the `\color{...}` by putting it within `{ }`, otherwise all the text following the command will be typeset in red. Compiling this may cause some unwanted linking of `@cares.com`, while leaving `who` unlinked.
2. The [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) does allow linking through a number of commands. You're probably interested in using the `\url{...}` command, since it takes care of the tricky `@` that has to be escaped in order to be typeset. It will also take care of breaking the email address (or url) across lines, if needed.

   ```
   \usepackage[%
     colorlinks=true,%
     urlcolor=red%
   ]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
   ...
   My email address is \url{who@cares.com}.
   ```

   [image: Email address typeset using hyperref's url command]

   This is also not entire accurate if you want to hyperlink to an email (via a `mailto` protocol).
3. Using `hyperref`'s `\href{<url>}{<text>}` provides the correct action:

   ```
   \usepackage[%
     colorlinks=true,%
     urlcolor=red%
   ]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
   ...
   My email address is \href{mailto:who@cares.com}{who@cares.com}.
   ```

   [image: Email address using hyperref and mailto: protocol]

   You can also typeset the email address in a different shape using, say, `\texttt{who@cares.com}`. Then it will be typeset similarly to that of option 2.

Comment: This is the better answer. Always make sure that the email link actually contains the email address, as a printed PDF should still be usable. While a clickable link (with the `mailto` protocol) is good for users reading the PDF on a computer, a reader of the printed PDF should be able to type the address in order to send an email.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the options `colorlinks=true` and `urlcolor=<color>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=olive]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\url{gmedina@tex.stackexchange}

\href{gmedina@tex.stackexchange}{gm-email}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, there's my mistake. I just typed the email in text (PDF reader recognized it as a link nevertheless). I didn't put in \url or \href{...}